# How do get specific version from a different branch to my branch on TFS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, tfs-2015

I created a branch from the main branch for example branch A. Now is there a way to get specific version of the main branch in branch A? I know that i can create branch from specific version of the other branch but i don't know how to do that for an existing branch that has been already created.

Comment: Are you talking about Git, or TFVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using TFVC, you can use `tf merge` command. See the detailed info about this command from [Merge command (Team Foundation Version Control)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/merge-command?view=azure-devops).

Open a command prompt from your workspace folder. The following example merges changeset 11 from `Main` branch into `branchA` branch.

```
tf merge /version:C11~C11 Main branchA /recursive
```

In changeset 11, I added a `test3.txt` file into the Main branch. After running the above command, you can see the `test3.txt` file in branchA. Then you can check in to reflect your server.
[image]

You can also do it in VS. Right click your Main branch -> Branching and Merging -> Merge -> Select **Selected changesets**.
[image]

Comment: Hi @Mahsa stz, have you tried to use `tf merge` command or manually merger in VS? Does it work for you?

Comment: Thanks @Zyiang Liu-MSFT it worked for me, I merged it manually in the VS